# C# MySql DataGrid Updater

Tags: c#, mysql

This is my Code to View Data from DataBase into Grid View. Can Anyone help me how to update data into database through updating data in Same GridView

Heres My Code

```
            string myConnection = "datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=2905";
            MySqlConnection myConn = new MySqlConnection(myConnection);

            MySqlCommand cmdDataBase = new MySqlCommand("select * from mydb.stud_info where stud_id = '" + this.studentid_txt.Text + "'; ", myConn);

            MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter();
            sda.SelectCommand = cmdDataBase;
            DataTable dbdataset = new DataTable();

            sda.Fill(dbdataset);
            BindingSource bSource = new BindingSource();

            bSource.DataSource = dbdataset;
            grid1.DataSource = bSource;
            sda.Update(dbdataset);
```

Comment: This is not a stellar example (I need to fix it with `using`) but check this out [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34175019) that I wrote

Comment: I hope that none of your users know what is an Sql Injection attack

Answer (score 0):

this is a faster method just one line and it will update everything in your datagridview

```
this.vesselTableTableAdapter.Update(this.dockMasterDbDataSet.VesselTable);
```